# what should be the file location in python for gpread credentials to be accessed by ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name

Tags: python, file, reference, gspread

what should be the file location in python for gpread credentials to be accessed by ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name?

this is my code:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('PythonGspread-c6fb2247fb25.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
sheet = client.open("Python").sheet1

# Make sure you use the right name here.
# Extract and print all of the values
list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
'result = sheet.cell(2,1).value'
print(list_of_hashes)
print("\n")
print(result)
input("Press enter to exit ;)")`
```

Comment: C:\Python\Python36>py spreadsheet.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spreadsheet.py", line 5, in <module>
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('PythonGspread-c6fb2247fb25.json', scope)
  File "C:\Users\Krishna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 219, in from_json_keyfile_name
    with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PythonGspread-c6fb2247fb25.json'

Comment: outcome of the code above comment

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the above issue.

New issue being

`gspread.exceptions.APIError: {`
 `"error": {`
  `"errors": [`
   `{`
    `"domain": "global",`
    `"reason": "insufficientPermissions",`
    `"message": "Insufficient Permission"`
   `}`
  `],`
  `"code": 403,`
`"message": "Insufficient Permission"  }`
`}`

i have shared the spreadsheet with the email given email present in the credentials.

Comment: Hi Krishna, can you please share how you fixed your original problem? I am also facing it right now.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the scope to this:

```
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
```

Comment: Thanks @Alon for this useful answer but I don't understand what is the importance of this scope and what does it do?